# Rare JSON issue: Well parsed but I cant get values. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Here is a JSON string, tested in some lints at https://jsonlint.com/ 
and they all say it's ok, I guess you will feel this as a redundant question and I understand. But I got stuck and I'm becoming crazy with this issue, unable to fix it by my own.

So I parse the JSON string this way (data var contents on the bottom):

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

And I have tried to get the data as usual:

```
console.log(data.result); or console.log(data['result']);
```

But it always is `undefined`. Can somebody help me?

Here the contents of var data:

```
var data = '{"result":"true","id":"31","content":"{"project":{"title":"New","description":"A new file","template":"cve"},"elements":[{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-1","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-1","eleType":"EXPERIENCE"},{"eleTarget":"page-2","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-2","eleType":"EDUCATION"},{"eleTarget":"page-3","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-3","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-4","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-4","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-5","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-5","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-6","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-6","eleType":"CREDENTIALS"}],"pages":[{"titleName":"page-0-title","titleValue":"About","fields":[{"fieName":"page-0-ele-0","fieValue":"Mark"},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-1","fieValue":"Hilton"},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-2","fieValue":"A creative"},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-3","fieValue":"developer"},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-4","fieValue":"Grown in the forest educated by robots."},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-5","fieValue":"Some Icon links"}]},{"titleName":"page-1-title","titleValue":"Experience","fields":[{"fieName":"page-1-ele-6","fieValue":"Experience"},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-0","fieValue":"Magic developer"},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-1","fieValue":"Wizards Ltd."},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-2","fieValue":"Providence"},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-3","fieValue":"2011"},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-4","fieValue":"Create essential magic texts and script code."}]},{"titleName":"page-2-title","titleValue":"Education","fields":[{"fieName":"page-2-ele-7","fieValue":"Education"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-0","fieValue":"Junior Wizard"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-1","fieValue":"Advanced spell management"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-2","fieValue":"Howards"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-3","fieValue":"2001"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-4","fieValue":"Denver"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-5","fieValue":"Texas"}]},{"titleName":"page-3-title","titleValue":"Skills","fields":[{"fieName":"page-3-ele-8","fieValue":"Skills"},{"fieName":"page-3-ele-9","fieValue":"Mobile-First  Responsive DesignCross Browser Testing & Debugging Agile Development & Scrum"}]},{"titleName":"page-4-title","titleValue":"Interests","fields":[{"fieName":"page-4-ele-10","fieValue":"Interests"},{"fieName":"page-4-ele-11","fieValue":"Apart from being a web developer, I enjoy most of my time being outdoors."}]},{"titleName":"page-5-title","titleValue":"Awards","fields":[{"fieName":"page-5-ele-12","fieValue":"Awards"},{"fieName":"page-5-ele-13","fieValue":"No awards yet"}]},{"titleName":"page-6-title","titleValue":"Personal details","fields":[{"fieName":"page-6-ele-14","fieValue":"Personal details"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-0","fieValue":"Mark"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-1","fieValue":"Hilton"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-2","fieValue":"Dakota"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-3","fieValue":" 214 987 548 415"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-4","fieValue":"hilton43@email.com"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-5","fieValue":"04-11-78"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-6","fieValue":"Denver TX"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-7","fieValue":"USA"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-8","fieValue":"32,Elm street, Providence NY"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-9","fieValue":"picture"}]}]}","status":"0","edited":"2017-12-08 23:02:28","views":"0"}';
```

Comment: Uh, if that's how it prints in the console, that's invalid json.  Valid json does not need to escape the double quotes.  If that's not what would be logged to the console if you just logged data, please provide us with that.

Comment: I have tried without backslashes too the, it returns a invalid character in the r of result

Comment: var data = "{"result":"true".....

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 3

Comment: Can you format better the JSON in your question?

Comment: @Taplar That's not true. Since he has it in a double-quoted JS string, he does need to escape the other double quotes. Though, the JSON still is invalid for other reasons and can't be parsed

Comment: I agree  vqdave, but JSON checker says its ok, is there any forbidden char or something?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
var data = '{"result":"true","id":"31","content":{"project":{"title":"New","description":"A new file","template":"cve"},"elements":[{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-1","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-1","eleType":"EXPERIENCE"},{"eleTarget":"page-2","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-2","eleType":"EDUCATION"},{"eleTarget":"page-3","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-3","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-4","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-4","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-5","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-5","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-6","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-6...","titleValue":"Awards","fields":[{"fieName":"page-5-ele-12","fieValue":"Awards"},{"fieName":"page-5-ele-13","fieValue":"No awards yet"}]},{"titleName":"page-6-title","titleValue":"Personal details","fields":[{"fieName":"page-6-ele-14","fieValue":"Personal details"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-0","fieValue":"Mark"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-1","fieValue":"Hilton"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-2","fieValue":"Dakota"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-3","fieValue":" 214 987 548 415"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-4","fieValue":"hilton43@email.com"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-5","fieValue":"04-11-78"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-6","fieValue":"Denver TX"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-7","fieValue":"USA"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-8","fieValue":"32,Elm street, Providence NY"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-9","fieValue":"picture"}]}]},"status":"0","edited":"2017-12-08 23:02:28","views":"0"}';
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON isn't parseable. There were a few errors with it, such as an extra `"` after `"content":` and before `"status":`. Here is the updated JSON:

```
{
    "result": "true",
    "id": "31",
    "content": {
        "project": {
            "title": "New",
            "description": "A new file",
            "template": "cve"
        },
        "elements": [{
            "eleTarget": "page-0",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-0",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-0",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-0",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-0",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-0",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-1",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-1",
            "eleType": "EXPERIENCE"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-2",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-2",
            "eleType": "EDUCATION"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-3",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-3",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-4",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-4",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-5",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-5",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-6",
            "eleType": "TEXT"
        }, {
            "eleTarget": "page-6",
            "eleType": "CREDENTIALS"
        }],
        "pages": [{
            "titleName": "page-0-title",
            "titleValue": "About",
            "fields": [{
                "fieName": "page-0-ele-0",
                "fieValue": "Mark"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-0-ele-1",
                "fieValue": "Hilton"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-0-ele-2",
                "fieValue": "A creative"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-0-ele-3",
                "fieValue": "developer"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-0-ele-4",
                "fieValue": "Grown in the forest educated by robots."
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-0-ele-5",
                "fieValue": "Some Icon links"
            }]
        }, {
            "titleName": "page-1-title",
            "titleValue": "Experience",
            "fields": [{
                "fieName": "page-1-ele-6",
                "fieValue": "Experience"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-1-ele-0-0",
                "fieValue": "Magic developer"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-1-ele-0-1",
                "fieValue": "Wizards Ltd."
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-1-ele-0-2",
                "fieValue": "Providence"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-1-ele-0-3",
                "fieValue": "2011"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-1-ele-0-4",
                "fieValue": "Create essential magic texts and script code."
            }]
        }, {
            "titleName": "page-2-title",
            "titleValue": "Education",
            "fields": [{
                "fieName": "page-2-ele-7",
                "fieValue": "Education"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-2-ele-0-0",
                "fieValue": "Junior Wizard"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-2-ele-0-1",
                "fieValue": "Advanced spell management"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-2-ele-0-2",
                "fieValue": "Howards"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-2-ele-0-3",
                "fieValue": "2001"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-2-ele-0-4",
                "fieValue": "Denver"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-2-ele-0-5",
                "fieValue": "Texas"
            }]
        }, {
            "titleName": "page-3-title",
            "titleValue": "Skills",
            "fields": [{
                "fieName": "page-3-ele-8",
                "fieValue": "Skills"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-3-ele-9",
                "fieValue": "Mobile-First  Responsive DesignCross Browser Testing & Debugging Agile Development & Scrum"
            }]
        }, {
            "titleName": "page-4-title",
            "titleValue": "Interests",
            "fields": [{
                "fieName": "page-4-ele-10",
                "fieValue": "Interests"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-4-ele-11",
                "fieValue": "Apart from being a web developer, I enjoy most of my time being outdoors."
            }]
        }, {
            "titleName": "page-5-title",
            "titleValue": "Awards",
            "fields": [{
                "fieName": "page-5-ele-12",
                "fieValue": "Awards"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-5-ele-13",
                "fieValue": "No awards yet"
            }]
        }, {
            "titleName": "page-6-title",
            "titleValue": "Personal details",
            "fields": [{
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-14",
                "fieValue": "Personal details"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-0",
                "fieValue": "Mark"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-1",
                "fieValue": "Hilton"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-2",
                "fieValue": "Dakota"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-3",
                "fieValue": " 214 987 548 415"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-4",
                "fieValue": "hilton43@email.com"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-5",
                "fieValue": "04-11-78"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-6",
                "fieValue": "Denver TX"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-7",
                "fieValue": "USA"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-8",
                "fieValue": "32,Elm street, Providence NY"
            }, {
                "fieName": "page-6-ele-0-9",
                "fieValue": "picture"
            }]
        }]
    },
    "status": "0",
    "edited": "2017-12-08 23:02:28",
    "views": "0"
}
```

Or in string JS form:

```js
var data = '{"result":"true","id":"31","content":{"project":{"title":"New","description":"Anewfile","template":"cve"},"elements":[{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-0","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-1","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-1","eleType":"EXPERIENCE"},{"eleTarget":"page-2","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-2","eleType":"EDUCATION"},{"eleTarget":"page-3","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-3","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-4","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-4","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-5","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-5","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-6","eleType":"TEXT"},{"eleTarget":"page-6","eleType":"CREDENTIALS"}],"pages":[{"titleName":"page-0-title","titleValue":"About","fields":[{"fieName":"page-0-ele-0","fieValue":"Mark"},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-1","fieValue":"Hilton"},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-2","fieValue":"Acreative"},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-3","fieValue":"developer"},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-4","fieValue":"Grownintheforesteducatedbyrobots."},{"fieName":"page-0-ele-5","fieValue":"SomeIconlinks"}]},{"titleName":"page-1-title","titleValue":"Experience","fields":[{"fieName":"page-1-ele-6","fieValue":"Experience"},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-0","fieValue":"Magicdeveloper"},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-1","fieValue":"WizardsLtd."},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-2","fieValue":"Providence"},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-3","fieValue":"2011"},{"fieName":"page-1-ele-0-4","fieValue":"Createessentialmagictextsandscriptcode."}]},{"titleName":"page-2-title","titleValue":"Education","fields":[{"fieName":"page-2-ele-7","fieValue":"Education"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-0","fieValue":"JuniorWizard"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-1","fieValue":"Advancedspellmanagement"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-2","fieValue":"Howards"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-3","fieValue":"2001"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-4","fieValue":"Denver"},{"fieName":"page-2-ele-0-5","fieValue":"Texas"}]},{"titleName":"page-3-title","titleValue":"Skills","fields":[{"fieName":"page-3-ele-8","fieValue":"Skills"},{"fieName":"page-3-ele-9","fieValue":"Mobile-FirstResponsiveDesignCrossBrowserTesting&DebuggingAgileDevelopment&Scrum"}]},{"titleName":"page-4-title","titleValue":"Interests","fields":[{"fieName":"page-4-ele-10","fieValue":"Interests"},{"fieName":"page-4-ele-11","fieValue":"Apartfrombeingawebdeveloper,Ienjoymostofmytimebeingoutdoors."}]},{"titleName":"page-5-title","titleValue":"Awards","fields":[{"fieName":"page-5-ele-12","fieValue":"Awards"},{"fieName":"page-5-ele-13","fieValue":"Noawardsyet"}]},{"titleName":"page-6-title","titleValue":"Personaldetails","fields":[{"fieName":"page-6-ele-14","fieValue":"Personaldetails"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-0","fieValue":"Mark"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-1","fieValue":"Hilton"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-2","fieValue":"Dakota"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-3","fieValue":"214987548415"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-4","fieValue":"hilton43@email.com"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-5","fieValue":"04-11-78"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-6","fieValue":"DenverTX"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-7","fieValue":"USA"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-8","fieValue":"32,Elmstreet,ProvidenceNY"},{"fieName":"page-6-ele-0-9","fieValue":"picture"}]}]},"status":"0","edited":"2017-12-0823:02:28","views":"0"}';
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
console.log(data.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested JSON objects don't take quotes. Remove the quotes around your `content` object.

```
var data = '{"result":"true","id":"31","content":"{"nested":"object"}","status":"0"}';
JSON.parse(data); // SyntaxError
```

```
var data = '{"result":"true","id":"31","content":{"nested":"object"},"status":"0"}';
JSON.parse(data); // success
```

Comment: That's not true. If he was writing the JSON outside of a JS string, then this would be possible (though not necessary). Since he does have it in a string and is using `JSON.parse` to convert it into an object, removing the quotes around nested objects will make it invalid syntax

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now. You're right, he shouldn't have wrapped the entire `content` object (not the key, as I had misinterpreted) in double quotes. Nonetheless, this answer has already been given